# first value in associative query result array is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, associative-array

This is really odd... If pdo fetch mode is assoc, it returns wrong id column value. If mode is both, it returns wrong 'id' value, but [0] is fine.
Table structure

```
mysql> describe itemweap;

+---------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | int(11)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| userID              | int(11)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Tier                | int(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| damage              | int(7) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MaxUpgrades         | int(2)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CurrentUpgradeLevel | int(2)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| heroID              | int(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| status              | int(1) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hash                | char(32)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Code

```
function performSingleQuery($DBH, $query,$data) {
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
    if (!isset($STH))
        echo "STH NOT SET<br />"; 
    else if ($STH) {
        try {
            if (isset($data))
                $STH->execute($data);
            else $STH->execute();
            if ($STH->errorCode()[2] == 0) {
                return $STH->fetchAll(); 
            }
            else return null;
        }
        catch (PODexception $e) {
            echo $e->errorInfo;
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function performQueryAndGenerateTable($isSearchSpecific, $query, $exNTAR, $DBH, 
    $isProfile, $tableName, $title, $mode) {
    $rows = performSingleQuery($DBH, $query, null);
    print_r($rows); //checking values here
    ...
}
```

Query example:

```
SELECT A.id, A.userID, A.tier, A.damage, A.maxupgrades, A.heroID, A.CurrentUpgradeLevel, c.herohealth, d.heropower , e.herospellcastrate, f.heromovementspeed, g.herooffabpow, h.herodefabpow, i.itemweapeledmg, j.itemaddproj, k.defencehealth, L.defencepower, M.defencerange, N.defencespeed, O.itemweaprangedaltdmg, R.id, S.notes 
from itemweap A 
left join herohealth C on (C.id = A.id) 
left join heropower D on (D.id = A.id) 
left join herospellcastrate E on (E.id = A.id) 
left join heromovementspeed F on (F.id = A.id) 
left join herooffabpow G on (G.id = A.id) 
left join herodefabpow H on (H.id = A.id) 
left join itemweapeledmg I on (I.id = A.id) 
left join itemaddproj J on (J.id = A.id) 
left join defencehealth K on (K.id = A.id) 
left join defencepower L on (L.id = A.id) 
left join defencerange M on (M.id = A.id) 
left join defencespeed N on (N.id = A.id) 
left join itemweaprangedaltdmg O on (O.id = A.id) 
left join users R on (R.id = A.userID) 
left join notes S on (S.id = A.id) WHERE A.userID = 4 AND A.status = 1;
```

This query result from mysql console 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOLlK.jpg (very wide image)
id column is fine here. 
print_r outputs

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [userID] => 4 [tier] => 2 [damage] => 2 [maxupgrades] => 5 [heroID] => 3 [CurrentUpgradeLevel] => 5 [herohealth] => [heropower] => [herospellcastrate] => [heromovementspeed] => [herooffabpow] => [herodefabpow] => [itemweapeledmg] => 33 [itemaddproj] => [defencehealth] => [defencepower] => 55 [defencerange] => [defencespeed] => [itemweaprangedaltdmg] => [notes] => sdasdawdasdasda )

[1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [userID] => 4 [tier] => 2 [damage] => 155 [maxupgrades] => 5 [heroID] => 3 [CurrentUpgradeLevel] => 5 [herohealth] => [heropower] => [herospellcastrate] => [heromovementspeed] => [herooffabpow] => [herodefabpow] => [itemweapeledmg] => 55 [itemaddproj] => [defencehealth] => [defencepower] => 5 [defencerange] => [defencespeed] => [itemweaprangedaltdmg] => [notes] => ) 

[2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [userID] => 4 [tier] => 2 [damage] => 1200 [maxupgrades] => 3 [heroID] => 4 [CurrentUpgradeLevel] => 3 [herohealth] => 12 [heropower] => [herospellcastrate] => [heromovementspeed] => [herooffabpow] => [herodefabpow] => [itemweapeledmg] => 259 [itemaddproj] => 4 [defencehealth] => [defencepower] => [defencerange] => [defencespeed] => [itemweaprangedaltdmg] => 16 [notes] => ) )
```

Id values is broken on every row.
But if I change fetch mode to both, print_r gives me

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [0] => 90 [userID] => 4 [1] => 4 [tier] => 2 [2] => 2 [damage] => 2 [3] => 2 [maxupgrades] => 5 [4] => 5 [heroID] => 3 [5] => 3 [CurrentUpgradeLevel] => 5 [6] => 5 [herohealth] => [7] => [heropower] => [8] => [herospellcastrate] => [9] => [heromovementspeed] => [10] => [herooffabpow] => [11] => [herodefabpow] => [12] => [itemweapeledmg] => 33 [13] => 33 [itemaddproj] => [14] => [defencehealth] => [15] => [defencepower] => 55 [16] => 55 [defencerange] => [17] => [defencespeed] => [18] => [itemweaprangedaltdmg] => [19] => [20] => 4 [notes] => sdasdawdasdasda [21] => sdasdawdasdasda ) 

[1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [0] => 91 [userID] => 4 [1] => 4 [tier] => 2 [2] => 2 [damage] => 155 [3] => 155 [maxupgrades] => 5 [4] => 5 [heroID] => 3 [5] => 3 [CurrentUpgradeLevel] => 5 [6] => 5 [herohealth] => [7] => [heropower] => [8] => [herospellcastrate] => [9] => [heromovementspeed] => [10] => [herooffabpow] => [11] => [herodefabpow] => [12] => [itemweapeledmg] => 55 [13] => 55 [itemaddproj] => [14] => [defencehealth] => [15] => [defencepower] => 5 [16] => 5 [defencerange] => [17] => [defencespeed] => [18] => [itemweaprangedaltdmg] => [19] => [20] => 4 [notes] => ) 

[2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [0] => 83 [userID] => 4 [1] => 4 [tier] => 2 [2] => 2 [damage] => 1200 [3] => 1200 [maxupgrades] => 3 [4] => 3 [heroID] => 4 [5] => 4 [CurrentUpgradeLevel] => 3 [6] => 3 [herohealth] => 12 [7] => 12 [heropower] => [8] => [herospellcastrate] => [9] => [heromovementspeed] => [10] => [herooffabpow] => [11] => [herodefabpow] => [12] => [itemweapeledmg] => 259 [13] => 259 [itemaddproj] => 4 [14] => 4 [defencehealth] => [15] => [defencepower] => [16] => [defencerange] => [17] => [defencespeed] => [18] => [itemweaprangedaltdmg] => 16 [19] => 16 [20] => 4 [notes] => [21] => ) )
```

Associative part is wrong again, but index part is fine. How can I make fetch_assoc return right values?

Comment: How is it wrong? the arrays appear identical if you consider only the associative keys. If you're getting "wrong" values, then your query is doing something wrong. changin fetch modes doesn't change the results. it just changes what you get from the fetch calls.

Comment: id value is 4, but if i run this query from mysql console, its 90,91 and 83 (on screenshot)

Comment: You have 2 columns in your SELECT that will be named 'id' in the output array, `A.id` and `R.id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` key is referring to the value of R.id in your query.  You need to alias the field names in your query so that they are all unique.

e.g.:

`SELECT A.id AS A_id, .... ,R.id AS R_id ....`

Then, your assoc array will have `A_id` and `R_id` as keys with appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to change my query and if it will work accept your answer.